# wpf binding change of binding source

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have following class as the main window:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Network network { get; set; }
    public DataSet data_set { get; set; }
    public Training training { get; set; }

    public string CurrentFile { get; set; }

    public MGTester tester;
    public MCTester testerSSE;

    public ChartWindow ErrorWindow;
    public ChartWindow TimesWindow;

    public Window1()
    {
        network = new Network();
        data_set = new DataSet();
        training = new Training();
        tester = new MGTester();
        testerSSE = new MCTester();
        CurrentFile = "";
        ErrorWindow = new ChartWindow();
        TimesWindow = new ChartWindow();

        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < tester.GetDeviceCount(); ++i)
        {
            DeviceComboBox.Items.Add(tester.GetDeviceName(i));
        }
    }...
```

And in my xaml code I have:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NetworkListview" ItemsSource="{Binding network.Layers}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="layer name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="neurons" CellTemplate="{StaticResource NeuronsTemplate}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="110" Header="activation" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ActivationTemplate}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Anyway I am binding to some member of Window1...
And it works fine but I want to change the member that controlls are binded to - 
I mean I want to do somthing like that in Window1

```
this.network = new Network();
```

When I do this binding stops working - How I can easily and nicely just "refresh" the binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your binding source is not a UI-class, use a notifying property instead of an auto one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Network _network;

    public Network Network
    {
        get
        {
            return _network;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _network)
            {
                _network = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(value);
            }
        }
    }


    protected NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

If your source class is a UI-class, define Network to be a DependencyProperty:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx

Example quoted from above link:

```
public class MyStateControl : ButtonBase
{
  public MyStateControl() : base() { }
  public Boolean State
  {
    get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(StateProperty, value); } 
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "State", typeof(Boolean), typeof(MyStateControl),new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to refresh the binding, but most of the time, there are better ways to it: either make your property into a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx), or put the data into another class that implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.